# Как рассчитать динамику год к году менти без сессий в Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

У меня есть две связанные таблицы users и sessions.

Связи:

> 1. users.user_id = sessions.mentee_id
> 2. users.reg_date = календарь.Date
> 3. sessions.session_date_time = календарь.Date

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Во-первых нужно сделать меру для расчета менти без сессий.

Это все users.user_id, которых нет в sessions.mentee_id.

Эта мера готова:

```
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        RELATEDTABLE('users'), 
        'users'[role] = "mentee" && 
        CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(sessions[mentee_id]), ALLSELECTED(sessions[mentee_id])) = 0))
```

Но далее возникает проблема. Как сделать аналогичный расчет за прошлый период (как добавить PREVIOUSYEAR('_календарь_auto'[Date])?

Как правило я делаю в мере 2 переменных: за выбранный год и за предыдущий.

P. S. На дашборде сделан срез по полю календарь.year (по году).

Answer (score 0):

Решить задачку я смог, но меня интересует, есть ли более лаконичное решение задачи?

```
VAR Cur_year =
COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            RELATEDTABLE('users'), 
            'users'[role] = "mentee" && 
            CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(sessions[mentee_id]), ALLSELECTED(sessions[mentee_id])) = 0))

VAR Prev_year =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(
        FILTER(
            RELATEDTABLE('users'), 
            'users'[role] = "mentee" && 
            CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(sessions[mentee_id]), ALLSELECTED(sessions[mentee_id])) = 0)),
    PREVIOUSYEAR('_календарь_auto'[Date]))

return

Cur_year/Prev_year-1
```